# Impossible integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{0}^{x^2-1} f(t) dt= x^6+x^4+3x^2$$

I saw this problem in a calculus exam. $f$ is assumed to be continuous. Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, I calculated $f(t)= 3t^2+8t+8 $. But when I integrate $f$ it gives me $\int_{0}^{x^2-1} f(t) dt= x^6+x^4+3x^2-5$:

$$\frac {d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x^2-1} f(t) dt= \frac {d}{dx}[x^6+x^4+3x^2]$$

$$f(x^2-1)2x = 6x^5+4x^3+6x$$
$$f(x^2-1) = 3x^4+2x^2+3$$
$$f(x^2-1) = 3(x^2-1)^2+8(x^2-1)+8$$
$$f(t) = 3t^2+8t+8$$
$$\int_{0}^{x^2-1} 3t^2+8t+8 dt= x^6+x^4+3x^2-5$$

This means that there is no continuous function that satisfies the equation of the problem?

Comment: You should show your derivation.  For instance, did you use the Chain Rule when you applied the FTC?

Comment: Also, what is the actual problem?  Is it to find such an $f$?  Is it to find ALL such $f$?  Is it to prove whether or not such an $f$ can actually exist?  Is it to compute something else?

Comment: The problem is to find an f. I added my derivation.

Comment: Very nice updates.  Thanks.

Comment: The case $x=1$ gives $\int_0^0f(t)dt=5$, but the left-hand side should be $0$.

Comment: Something interesting here.  You nicely deduce that $f(x^2-1) = 3x^4+2x^2+3$.  You then conclude that $f(x) =3x^2+8x+8$.  But that might not be the *only* solution to your polynomial relation.  You've argued that this *particular* one creates a contradiction, but how do you know your $f$ is the unique one?  (It may not be:  this isn't clear to me.)  We now know the answer is that no continuous $f$'s exist, but I think the problem of solving your polynomial relation is an interesting one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that this does mean there are no continuous functions satisfying the equation. (There's a quicker way to see this: set $x=1$, then $LHS=0$, but $RHS=5$.)

Comment: This is the way to do it.  +1

Comment: You're right. Thank you very much

Comment: Does this work because, since nothing is said about $x$, the equality must hold for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and so it suffices to show a single value such that it doesn't hold to conclude? Another question: the continuity of $f$ is required only to be sure that $f$ is integrable?

Comment: @Gwyn  yes on both counts.

Comment: @Randall: Thank you!

Comment: @Gwyn You don't need $f$ to be continuous to be integrable,  you can be discontinuous at a "small" number of points (Finite,  countable,  or in more general,  Lebesgue Measure 0 which is a concept you'll get to later).

Comment: @Alan: Ok, so my question is: why asking for $f$ to be continuous and not only integrable? Maybe In order to be able to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: It is because it is a calculus class, not measure theory.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $f(t)=at^2+bt+c$

we have
$$\int_0^{x^2-1} \left(a t^2+b t+c\right) \, dt=$$
$$=x^6+x^4+3 x^2\equiv \frac{a x^6}{3}+x^4 \left(\frac{b}{2}-a\right)+x^2 (a-b+c)-\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}-c$$
and
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{a }{3}=1\\
\frac{b}{2}-a=1\\
a-b+c=3\\
-\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}-c=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
the system has no solution, therefore there is no polynomial $f(t)=at^2+bt+c$ which satisfies the equation.

Comment: yes, I also did the same reasoning. But what is the solution? Is there a continuous f that satisfies the equation?

Comment: @Dedekind93 An integral which gives a polynomial and is not a polynomial? IMO it is impossible

Comment: There is a solution for $$\int_{-1}^{x^2-1} f(t) dt= x^6+x^4+3x^2$$

Comment: I don’t think it’s clear that $f$ must be polynomial.  It must satisfy a polynomial relation for sure, but so do sines and cosines.

Comment: @Raffaele surely it’s possible. Consider $\int_0^{x^3}t^{-1/3}dt$.